# Can you create multiple ttk treeview heading styles in a single application?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a tkinter app written in python 3 that uses multiple treeview widgets across different toplevel frames. I want to customize the header styles differently for each widget, but I only know how to change the global "Treeview.Heading" style. Here is how I currently define my treeview styles:

```
self.xs_font = tkfont.Font(family='Arial', size=9)
self.treeview = ttk.Style()
def fixed_map(option):#bug fix to allow highlighted lines in a treeview
    return [elm for elm in self.treeview.map('Treeview', query_opt=option) if elm[:2] != ('!disabled', '!selected')]
self.treeview.map('Treeview', foreground=fixed_map('foreground'),background=fixed_map('background'))#implement bug fix
self.treeview.configure('home_tree.Treeview',font=self.xs_font,rowheight=20)# style for homepage treeview
self.treeview.configure('toplevel_tree.Treeview',font=self.xs_font,rowheight=30)#style for toplevel treeview
self.treeview.configure('Treeview.Heading',font=self.xs_font,rowheight=20)#style for treeview headings (applies to all treeviews)
```

What I'd like is to create custom styles for each treeview heading and apply them, just as I do for the body of the treeview.

Comment: Did you try the obvious? home_tree.Treeview.Heading instead of Treeview.Heading

Comment: @Atlas435 *facepalm - yep, this worked. Thanks for the quick fix :)